# How can this function be faster? Solving for a row of Pascal's triangle

Tags: python

I saw a posting on Hacker News this morning that was ranting about people not being able to solve an interview question. I thought I would give it a shot, but I would like to know how my attempt could be improved.

```
def get_pascal_row(n):
    """
    Returns the nth row of Pascal's Triangle for a given n. Uses
    Gray's algorithm.
    """
    if n == 0: return []
    n -= 1
    row = [1]
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
        row.append(row[-1] * n/i)
        n -= 1
    return row
```

Comment: Stop half way through and stick a copy of the first half reversed to the end of your return.

Answer (score 3):

You can [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the rows you have already computed previously.

Alternatively, you could compute it in closed form using the [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

[image]

Start looking in [`scipy.special.binom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html).